# Form submitted twice after updating from ASP MVC 3 Preview to Beta

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

After upgrading my ASP MVC from 3 Preview to 3 Beta I see strange behaviour in my Ajax forms.

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("New", new AjaxOptions() {OnSuccess = "onAjaxSuccess", OnFailure = "onAjaxFailure", OnBegin = "onAjaxBegin", HttpMethod = "Post"})) {}

<form action="/Order/New" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="onAjaxBegin" data-ajax-failure="onAjaxFailure" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-success="onAjaxSuccess" method="post"></form>
```

I have placed an `alert` inside my function `onAjaxBegin` and it is beeing fired twice, each time i click on my submit button.

Anyone else seen this behaviour? I have not changed anything in the code after upgrading, and it worked perfectly before the upgrade.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem, and i found the solution: I included the "`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`"`-Script` twice :-)

Comment: you saved my day :) don't know why bundle was including both dev and min versions of unobtrusive.ajax script

Comment: Mine too. This should certainly be the answer for this question.

Comment: Thanks! 5 years passed, version 3.2.3 of Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax package and still this issue if it is included twice.

Comment: Man-Oh-Man... This is a royal pain.  It also helps to explicitly include the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in the BundleConfig.cs in the right place (reference to a comment in this same article below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778506/3393832) -

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));`

NOT here -

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));` as a catch all (*) reference.

Answer (score 14):

Look at the generated HTML. [In ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes) there's new support for unobtrusive jquery based ajax and all the Ajax helpers use jquery now. Maybe there's something left with MS Ajax which causes the double call. Make sure you remove all the inclusions of MSAjax scripts from the page. Also why using `Ajax.BeginForm` when you could simply use `Html.BeginForm` with unobtrusive jquery?

Comment: Than you, it worked after I removed the reference to the old MSAjax scripts!

Comment: @IamStalker, example of what?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Html.BeginForm with unobtrusive ajax ]jquery?

Answer (score 7):

The duplicated `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` can also happened if your controller returns a `View()` instead of `PartialView()`.

Comment: Double checked all suggestions except this one. I assumed I was doing rightly. But in last checked it too. Finally was able to crack it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using a `AJAX.BeginForm` call that is loaded dynamically using `$.load()` 
I solved it by removing the extra include of **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** on the loaded form. That's the key!

Answer (score 2):

one small tip all the time before you using `.live()`, do .`die()` :)
this will kill all the java scripts attached to this event and will create a new one.

example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#MyInfoForm').die();
    $("#MyInfoForm").live('submit', function(e) {
        //some code
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference for those using ASP.NET MVC; `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"` does **also** include `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"`.

So if your `BundleConfig` looks like this;

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

It will result in submitting an Ajax form twice. Removing either `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"` or `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"` will fix the problem.

Just posting this because it is easy to overlook `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"` when searching for `unobtrusive-ajax`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` instead of `live` in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js~~~ This is very important.Because `live` event will call the previous events every time but `bind` only calls the current event.

Answer (score 1):

Moving `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` outside partial-view solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this exact problem and for a very different reason. I had included the script reference to the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` within the div that got updated. Moving it outside the div fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had a login partial view in master page that included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`. I also had this file included in my view. So I removed one and the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for someone having a scenario similar to what I have:

On my page, the edit form opens a partial view inside a Kendo UI modal pop-up window, which loads the code of the form dynamically, including jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js. With this setting, - which can relate to any pop-up such as that of jQuery UI and not just Kendo UI - the behavior of form submission is as follows:

The first time the pop-up window is opened, the form submission causes a single call to the controller (server-side) code. So far so good. However, for the second time that the window is opened (without closing the container page), the form submission calls the controller 2 times. Subsequently, each re-opening of the pop-up window, causes an additional loading of the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js code, which in turn causes an additional unwanted call to the controller at each single submission of the form.

In order to fix the problem, I moved the inclusion of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js from the partial view of the pop-up window into the main page. However this made the client-side validation stop working, and to fix that, I used the solution provided in here: 
[client side validation with dynamically added field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965470/client-side-validation-with-dynamically-added-field) which links to this blog post:
http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, just remove all jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js references, since you are using the Ajax.BeginForm it will use the ajax normally.

So it doesn't has to disable the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

this is old but I found something really stupid that is easy to overlook.

Our form also had the following attached to it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit-button').on('click', function (e) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Obviously the .NET code handles this itself.