# How to make the jQuery valid function work reliably on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, validation

I have a problem on jQuery valid function. When on IE, it doesn't work, the valid always return true. I used this code: [client side validation with dynamically added field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965470/client-side-validation-with-dynamically-added-field)

Here's the chart:

```
                    Chrome      IE

jquery-1.6.1        works       not working
jquery-1.4.4        works       works
```

1.6 doesn't work on IE too. However, 1.4.4 jQuery valid works on IE.

Here's the <strike>jsFiddle-friendly</strike> test (test this as local html):

```
<!--
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<form id="XXX">
    <input type="submit" id="Save" value="Save">

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

    // sourced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965470/client-side-validation-with-dynamically-added-field
    // which I do think don't have a bug
    (function ($) {


        $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent = function (selector) {
            //use the normal unobstrusive.parse method
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector);

            //get the relevant form
            var form = $(selector).first().closest('form');

            //get the collections of unobstrusive validators, and jquery validators
            //and compare the two
            var unobtrusiveValidation = form.data('unobtrusiveValidation');
            var validator = form.validate();

            $.each(unobtrusiveValidation.options.rules, function (elname, elrules) {
                if (validator.settings.rules[elname] == undefined) {
                    var args = {};
                    $.extend(args, elrules);
                    args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname];
                    $('[name=' + elname + ']').rules("add", args);
                } else {
                    $.each(elrules, function (rulename, data) {
                        if (validator.settings.rules[elname][rulename] == undefined) {
                            var args = {};
                            args[rulename] = data;
                            args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname][rulename];
                            $('[name=' + elname + ']').rules("add", args);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    })($);
    // ...sourced from others


    // my code starts here...
    $(function () {

        var html = "<input data-val='true' " +
           "data-val-required='This field is required' " + "name='inputFieldName' id='inputFieldId' type='text'/>";
        $("form").append(html);

        var scope = $('#XXX');

        $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent(scope);




        $('#Save').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(scope.valid());
        });

    });
    // ...my code ends here

</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried my code on jsFiddle, it has side-effect, the jQuery 1.6's valid is working on IE. Don't test this code on jsFiddle. Test this code on your local html

Comment: What version of IE did you use?

Comment: I've recently used the dynamic parse function you've found there and I cant seem to replicate the problem, seems to all be working on 1.6.1 and IE. Perhaps it has something to do with the way your adding a custom input with validation attached. Could you get this up and running on JSFiddle?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Some of it not even HTML/JS. If you minimize the amount of code you are much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: ok, i'll remove the ASP.NET MVC code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem has been solved. try version 1.8.1.

[Download jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: Second time today stackoverflow has saved me from going mad! cheers!

Comment: Perfect.  I had the same problem where calling valid didn't work in IE 8, but did work in FireFox.  Downloaded the latest JQUery Validation 1.8.1 and my problems went away.  Thanks Beygi

Answer (score 1):

Hi I also got the same problem and I have updated my both scripts file to the latest one and everything is working very fine on my side. Go to jquery.com and check for the latest jquery code file.