# ajax post cause my form multi submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

have a form the one item in it is suppose to be submitted view AJAX post ,
but when i'm posting the form is submitted few times white in the first time it only submit the AJAX item + values from ENUM dropdownlist,
and the rest of the items value is NUll ,so the model is not valid & after that i'm getting all the items except the item ajax suppose to post ...
the list of script I have in the page:
what i wish to submit(post) to my controller is the value :lat

```html
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/GenresScripts.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var initialCenter;
    var initialZoom;
    var elevationService;
    var geocoder;

    function init() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(52.373922, -3.427734),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

        map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), mapOptions);

        initialCenter = mapOptions.center;
        initialZoom = mapOptions.zoom;


        addGeocodingService();

        addShowCoords();

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init);


    function addGeocodingService() {
        geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
    }

    function geocodeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address },
            function(results, status) {
                if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    addShowCoords(results[0].geometry.location);
                    //var position = results[0].geometry.location;

                } else {
                    alert("Geocode failed with the following error: " + status);
                }

            });
    };


    function addShowCoords() {
        window.google.maps.event.addListener(map,
            'center_changed',
            function() {
                var newCenter = map.getCenter().toString();
                var lat = newCenter.toString();
                document.getElementById('LatLong').innerText = lat;

            });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //ActionName
            url: "Create",
            //Just for test hard code value 
            //Should be : data: { LatLong:lat},
            data: { LatLong: lat },
            async: false,
            datetype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                return false;

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("oops, something bad happened");
            }


        });

    };

</script>
```

Comment: You have numerous problems. `lat` is undefined in `addShowCoords()`. You call it inside `init()` with no parameters and then call it again inside `geocodeAddress()` but pass in parameters but function does nothing with that. Also adding event listener each time you call it. Also don't use `async:false` it is a terrible practice and is deprecated by browsers and you should see warning in console about that

Comment: Suggest you learn to use console logging in your code to debug..or learn how to use breakpoints in debugger

Answer (score 0):

The multiple submit occurs only if you load unobtrusive jquery more than once,so check your entire project and add only one unobtrusive jquery.

For more details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062568/form-submitted-twice-after-updating-from-asp-mvc-3-preview-to-beta)